# Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint slow response?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

First time I'm trying out the actuator dependency, I configured it to be opt-in

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
```

When I call `/actuator/health` locally it takes around 1.4 seconds to respond. Keep in mind this is a local call, from the same machine of the server.

If I create a regular endpoint that replies with an empty response, the request would take just a couple of milliseconds.

Is this normal? Can I make it reply faster?

Answer (score 1):

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63666118/1861769

> Basically health endpoint is implemented in a way that it contains a
> list of all Spring beans that implement the interface HealthIndicator.
>
> Each health indicator is responsible for supplying a health
> information about one subsystem (examples of such subsystem are:disk,
> postgres, mongo, etc.), spring boot comes with some predefined
> HealthIndicators.
>
> So that when the health endpoint is invoked, it iterates through this
> list and gets the information about each subsystem and then constructs
> the answer.
>
> Hence you can place a break point in relevant health indicators
> (assuming you know which subsystems are checked) and see what happens.
>
> If you're looking for the HTTP entry point - the code that gets called
> when you call http:///actuator/health (can vary depending
> on your settings but you get the idea)`, it can be found here
>
> Yet another approach that comes to mind is disabling "suspicious"
> health check and finding the slow one by elimination.
>
> For example, if you have an elastricsearch and would like to disable
> it, use in the application.properties:
>
> `management.health.elasticsearch.enabled = false`

Comment: You shouldn't copy and paste another person's answer unless you reference it. This is the original answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63666118/1861769